# Flutter camera autoFocus timeout erro

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou utilizando o Flutter câmera para criar um componente de câmera. O componente funciona relativamente bem, se não fosse pelo fato de que quando eu tento tirar uma footo desfocada, o componente retorna uma erro de timeout. Aparentemente o Flutter câmera tenta foca a foto em questão e acaba resultando nesse erro. Já estou a algum tempo tentando resolver este problema. Também não encontro nada online que funcione.

Este é o componente de câmera que desenvolvi:

```
class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _controllerInitializer;
  bool _toggleFlash = false;

  Future<CameraDescription> _getCamera() async {
    final c = await availableCameras();
    return c.first;
  }

  void onCapturePressed() async {
    try {
      final image = await _controller.takePicture();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConfirmPhotoPage(image)),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      _showErrorModal(
        'Error when trying to take a photo',
        'Make sure your camera is focused before taking the photo',
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCamera().then((camera) {
      if (camera == null) return;
      setState(() {
        _controller = CameraController(
          camera,
          ResolutionPreset.high,
        );
        _controllerInitializer = _controller.initialize();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget zoomButton(String label, VoidCallback callback) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: callback,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _controllerInitializer,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return CameraPreview(_controller);
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              CustomAppbar(
                'Camera',
                'Take a photo',
                true,
                () {
                  setState(() {
                    _toggleFlash = !_toggleFlash;
                  });
                  _toggleFlash
                      ? _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch)
                      : _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
                },
                flashValue: _toggleFlash,
              ),
              PainterFrame(),
              CustomBottombar(
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        zoomButton('1x', () => _controller.setZoomLevel(1.0)),
                        zoomButton('2x', () => _controller.setZoomLevel(2.0)),
                        zoomButton('3x', () => _controller.setZoomLevel(3.0)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    CameraMainActionButton(
                      true,
                      onCapturePressed,
                    ) //onCapturePressed
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future _showErrorModal(String title, String info) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return ErrorModal(title, info);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

A parte que mais me incomoda é que quando esse erro ocorre a câmera não consegue recuperar o foco a não ser re-iniciando a componente de câmera.

Alguém saberia como contornar este problema?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você pode tentar desativar o foco automático pra ver se te ajuda em algo... `cameraController.setFocusMode(FocusMode.locked); cameraController.setFocusPoint(null);`

Comment: @Matheus Ribeiro Obrigado pelo comentário mas não adiantou

Comment: @Matheus Ribeiro Outra coisa, não entendi como esse setFocusPoint() funciona, eu passei alguns valores de offset mas nada parece mudar.

Comment: Não cheguei a testar a utilização desse método, mas você pode tentar dar uma olhada no [exemplo](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example) disponível no package, que faz uso desse método, para entender melhor e ver se não falta algo a mais.